# como selecionar apenas 1 registro de cada id

Tags: mysql, sql

Após fazer um inner join entre as tabelas usuário (1) e imagem (N), a seguinte tabela é retornada (o id se refere ao id do usuário e o nome_do_arquivo ao arquivo da imagem):

| id | nome_do_arquivo

| 12 | img1.png

| 12 | img2.png

| 13 |img3.png

| 13 |img4.png

Como recuperar apenas 1 imagem de cada id? (sem usar o where = id, pois no momento da consulta, não possuo o id para fazer a comparação.)

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor o que deseja. Da forma que está não é possivel responder

Comment: Poste seu SQL também para analisarmos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT u.*, i.imagem as imagem_usuario FROM usuario u 
LEFT JOIN imagem i ON(i.id_usuario=u.id) GROUP BY u.id_usuario ORDER BY u.id_usuario ASC
```

Desta forma, conseguimos também ordenar pelo id, para saber se pega o primeiro registro ou o último registro.

Comment: Ver meu comentário para o Otto abaixo.

Comment: Sim, mas podemos ordenar neste caso.

Comment: Ordenar não adianta (no MySQL), precisaria fazer uma subquery.

Comment: Também seria possível

Answer (score 2):

Use um `Group By Id`

Algo do tipo

```
Select * from Tabela
Group By Id
```

Comment: O problema disso é que você não tem nenhum controle sobre *qual* imagem é retornada para determinado id, no exemplo dele.

Comment: Exatamente concordo @bfavaretto porém ele tambem não especificou isso ele quer que retorne uma, não qual

Comment: Ok, faz sentido. Mas acho que essa será a próxima pergunta dele ;)