# Listar apenas uma imagem de um produto

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um projeto, onde vai permitir que se cadastre mais de uma imagem por produto, isso vem me gerando uma certa dificuldade.
Queria que lista-se os produtos que possuem imagem e apenas uma imagem esse mesmo produto.

Obviamente talvez tenha forma mais fácil de fazer isso

Já tentei algumas formas que não vem dando o resultado correto que espero.

O que mais se aproxima do resultado final foi esse a baixo, porém duplica o produto que possuem mais de uma imagem

```
 SELECT DISTINCT *, (SELECT qc_imagens.img_nome  FROM qc_imagens
    JOIN qc_produtos on qc_produtos.pro_id = qc_imagens.img_pro_id 
         WHERE qc_imagens.img_nome <> NULL AND qc_imagens.img_excluido = '0'
        order by qc_imagens.img_id DESC
         LIMIT 1) AS nome_img 
         
         FROM qc_produtos p
 INNER JOIN qc_imagens img on img.img_pro_id = p.pro_id
 INNER JOIN qc_categorias c ON p.pro_categoria = c.cate_id
 WHERE pro_ativo = 1 AND img.img_excluido = '0'
```

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente agrupar pela coluna p.prod_id, por que ai isso força a pegar apenas a primeira linha, algo assim:

```
SELECT  *
FROM qc_produtos p
 INNER JOIN imagens AS img ON p.pro_id = img.img_pro_id 
 INNER JOIN qc_categorias c ON p.pro_categoria = c.cate_id
 WHERE pro_ativo = 1 AND img.img_excluido = '0'
 GROUP BY p.prod_id;
```

Comment: Não funcionou, eu não tenho o ER desse db, mas é bem isso mesmo

produtos  N --------------- 1 imagens

Um produto pode ter n imagens

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, mas se não der certo, tenta esse link tb: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96756/como-selecionar-apenas-1-registro-de-cada-id

Comment: Fala ai, até tinha conseguindo, porém sua forma bem mais enxuta, marquei como resolvido, brigado :) Tinha virado 2 subselect... uma gambs quase